# How might I go about integrated this WYMeditor plugin into Refinery CMS's WYMeditor?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refinerycms, wymeditor

This question may be deemed off-topic or broad - apologies in advance if it is deemed so.

- https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor/blob/master/src/wymeditor/plugins/table/jquery.wymeditor.table.js
- http://wymeditor.github.io/wymeditor/dist/examples/21-table-plugin.html

This plugin describes itself as "a Table editing plugin that gives the user ability to add and remove rows and columns as well as merge rows and columns" - this is the exactly what I need for my app's backend, powered by `Refinery CMS 2.1.2`.

- https://github.com/refinery/refinerycms/issues/1340
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/refinery-cms/wymeditor%2420plugin/refinery-cms/hflJlOBRawU/AYcaCItCoqYJ

These links lead me to believe that this feature request was never implemented but is definitely possible - I'm just wondering how.

One of the author's of the gem (Philip Arndt) hints, in the first link, that it may be a simple case of swapping out the existing `Refinery CMS` plugin.

I imagine I'm gonna need to determine that the plugin is compatible with the `Refinery CMS` I'm using and am gonna have to do a considerable amount of configuration and tweaking to get it to play nicely but I can't figure out where to start with this - what are the initial steps I have to take to at least get started? Does anyone else have experience in trying to tweak the toolbar of `Refinery CMS`'s WYMeditor?

Answer (score 1):

This will probably not be a complete answer.

I'd probably start by forking the CMS at the version (tag) I want.

In the clone, I would find the code that initialized the editor. I would look for `.wymeditor(` to find that code.

I would then look at [this example](https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor/blob/346d24925e3ebf0d8a7b781e546a96f28447217d/src/examples/21-table-plugin.html#L33).